# PHP strange "no input file specified" at ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, iis, input

Im having a big problem with this error "No input file specified". This error just doesnt make sense because the file is there and I can access normally through browser, and the stranger is: the error dont occour every time. I can solve this problem just by opening the file, modifying anything and saving it again. Doing this the error stops for a 2 or 3 days then just back with no reason.
Im using Php 7 over IIS, some rewrite rules that dont interfere on process because Im using the file path to call.

I thought thats its happening because the file is too big (2k lines), So I already tried somethigs without success:
Separated most javascript code from php file,
Reduced php code,
Added "?" on file name $("#divConteudo").load("ajax/cad.php?");
I call with parameter too $("#divConteudo").load("ajax/cad.php?id=1");

Example:

```
<?
 ...
$page = 'estrategia_cad.php';
 ...
?>
<script language="javascript">

 $("#divConteudo").load("<?=$page?>", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) 
 {
    if(statusTxt == "success"){
      alert("External content loaded successfully!");
    }
    if(statusTxt == "error"){
      alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText + '\r\n' + responseTxt);
    }
  }); 

</script>
```

Execution Result:

```
Error: 404: Page not found.
No input file specified
```

To solve it I have to modify anything in page 'estrategia_cad.php' and save it, this workaround keep working for a 2 - 3 days until the same problem occours again.

Tkz in advance guyz!

Comment: You don't give us enough context to understand what iks your problem. Please share your code, explain what should happen and what exactly is not working

Comment: Edited with example and code. @jeremycastelli

Comment: ok what is estrategia_cad.php ?
I'm not sure, but what's bothering me is that you want to load "estrategia_cad.php", where it should be something like https:// mysite.com/estrategia_cad.php

Comment: @jeremycastelli "estrategia_cad.php" is on the site root, like index.php, and this call is from index.php

Answer (score 0):

It was some bug with the file, if I just rename the file and back to original name all it works, dont know why, but it seems to be some bug in IIS working with PHP. To solve it I'd just created another file and pointed to that.